# Keeping source data format while creating new table

Tags: mysql, sql

How can we keep the original data formats from columns in tablets when we take columns from differnet tables to create a new  table ? I got 2 tables and want to create a new one based on some columns from each of them: But the date format from one column (date) in table1 is automatically amended (to varchar) when I perform the following (in the [] is the original data format):

```
CREATE TABLE 3 AS
SELECT
y1.ItemID[int],
y1.order[int],
y1.name[varchar],
y1.date[date],
y2.product_id[int],
y2.name[varchar],
y2.Kategorie [number],
FROM Table1 y1
LEFT JOIN Table2 y2
ON y1.ItemID = y2.product_id;
```

What´s wrong?

Comment: This should keep the data type. On the other hand, your code will already not work because you have two columns with the same name `name`, so maybe check again if that (apart from the `3`) is actually your code or if you simplified it too much. Also doublecheck if `y1.date` is really `date` type (`show create table y1`). If nothing works, you can explicitly set the datatypes in your code with `create table table3 (columns with types) as ...`

Answer (score 0):

You should able to cast explicitly:

```
CREATE TABLE 3 AS
SELECT
y1.ItemID,
y1.order,
y1.name,
Cast(y1.date as date) date,
y2.product_id,
y2.name,
y2.Kategorie 
FROM Table1 y1
LEFT JOIN Table2 y2
ON y1.ItemID = y2.product_id;
```

and you can also set the data type on the create, as shown on the mysql online manual example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (a TINYINT NOT NULL) SELECT b+1 AS a FROM bar;
```